# Information Exposure Through Sent Data (CWE ID 201) in vera code

Tags: javascript, veracode

```
window.top.location = "<%=AppProperties.getInstance().getProperty("Privacy")%>";
```

Iam getting vulnerablity on above the code in veracode.

> *Recommendation: Ensure that the transfer of sensitive data is intended and that it does not violate application security policy or
>   user expectations*

could you help me how to fix the vulnerablity?

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI.httpUtilities()---> This method get resolves the vulnerability in veracode and ESAPI is the library file of file of java. httpUtilities() this method provide additional security to our application.

let me know if u have any on above the issues!